# Multiple data sources as array in google charts dashboard api

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

**What I have done?**
I am building a dashboard with multiple data. The data are in form of arrays.

**What i need to implement?**
I have implemented the dashboard with the help of the tutorial but I am not able to implement another data source.

**Here is my code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>
          Google Visualization API Sample
        </title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawVisualization() {

// Prepare the data
      var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Type', 'Precheck Alarms', 'Postcheck Alarms'],
        ['Michael' , 'Type1', 12, 5],
        ['Elisa', 'Type2', 20, 7],
        ['Robert', 'Type1', 7, 3],
        ['John', 'Type1', 54, 2],
        ['Jessica', 'Type2', 22, 6],
        ['Aaron', 'Type1', 3, 1],
        ['Margareth', 'Type2', 42, 8],
        ['Miranda', 'Type2', 33, 6]
      ]);
       var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Type', 'Precheck Alarms', 'Postcheck Alarms'],
        ['Michael' , 'Type1', 12, 5],
        ['Elisa', 'Type2', 20, 7],
        ['Robert', 'Type1', 7, 3],
        ['John', 'Type1', 54, 2],
        ['Jessica', 'Type2', 22, 6],
        ['Aaron', 'Type1', 3, 1],
        ['Margareth', 'Type2', 42, 8],
        ['Miranda', 'Type2', 33, 6]
      ]);     

  // Define a category picker control for the Type column



 var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Type',
      'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false
      }
    }
  });

  // Define a Pie chart
  var columns_alarms = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'options': {
      'width': 600,
      'height': 600,
      'legend': 'none',
      'title': 'Alarms',
      'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
      //'pieSliceText': 'label'
    },
    // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
    // from the 'data' DataTable.
    'view': {'columns': [0, 2,3]}
  });

  // Define a table


 var table_alarms = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
      'width': '300px'
    }
  });
 var columns_kpi = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart4',
    'options': {
      'width': 600,
      'height': 600,
      'legend': 'none',
      'title': 'Alarms',
      'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
      //'pieSliceText': 'label'
    },

    // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
    // from the 'data' DataTable.
    'view': {'columns': [0, 2,3]}
  });

  // Define a table
  var table_kpi = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart5',
    'options': {
      'width': '300px'
    }
  });

  // Create a dashboard
  new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_alarms')).
  new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_kpi')).
      // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
      // picker will drive both charts.
      bind([categoryPicker], [columns_kpi, table_kpi,columns_alarms, table_alarms]).
      // Draw the entire dashboard.
      draw(data1);
      draw(data2);

}


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="dashboard">
      <table>
        <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
          <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
            <div id="control1"></div>
            <div id="control2"></div>
            <div id="control3"></div>
          </td>
          <td style='width: 600px'>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart4"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart5"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code renders WSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code.

```
 new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_alarms')).
 new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_kpi')).
```

should be

```
 new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_alarms'));
 new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_kpi')).
```

(the "." should be a ";" at the end of the first line)

Also in the same two lines you refer to elements with id `dashboard_alarms` and `dashboard_kpi` but you don't have those elements in your html. You should add the tags

```
<div id="dashboard_alarms"/>
<div id="dashboard_kpi"/>
```

to your html.

You can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug javascript code if you're using Firefox. Goole chrome might have a javascrpt debugger as well. With a javascript debugger you can diagnose the reason for such problems.

A working example of the code is available at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMjDz/).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my own question. needed to have to separate controls bound to each dashboard.
One can't share a control with two datasources for two dashboards.
just have a separate control and it all works.